# Is the reciprocal of the inverse tangent function, $\frac1{\arctan x}$, a (logarithmically) completely monotonic function on $(0,\infty)$?

Tags: convex-analysis, special-functions, laplace-transform, monotone-functions, inverse-laplace

A non-negative function $f$ is said to be completely monotonic on an interval $I$ if $f$ has derivatives of all orders on $I$ and
\begin{equation*}
0\le(-1)^{n-1}f^{(n-1)}(x)<\infty
\end{equation*}
for all $x\in I$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\dotsc\}$.

A positive function $f$ is said to be logarithmically completely monotonic on an interval $I$ if its logarithm $\ln f$ satisfies
\begin{equation*}
0\le(-1)^n[\ln f(x)]^{(n)}<\infty
\end{equation*}
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ on $I$.

If a function $f$ is non-identically zero and completely monotonic on $(0,\infty)$, then $f$ and its derivatives $f^{(n)}(x)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ are impossibly equal to $0$ on $(0,\infty)$.

A logarithmically completely function on an interval $I$ must be also completely monotonic on $I$, but not conversely.

The Bernstein--Widder theorem characterizes that a necessary and sufficient condition for $f$ to be completely monotonic on $(0,\infty)$ is that
\begin{equation}\label{Laplace-mu(t)-INT}\tag{1}
f(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}\textrm{d}\mu(t), \quad x\in(0,\infty),
\end{equation}
where $\mu(t)$ is non-decreasing and the above integral converges for $x\in(0,\infty)$.

- **Question 1: Is the reciprocal of the inverse tangent function, $\dfrac1{\arctan x}$, a (logarithmically) completely monotonic function on $(0,\infty)$?**
- **Question 2: If $\dfrac1{\arctan x}$ is a (logarithmically) completely monotonic function on $(0,\infty)$, can one give an explicit expression of the measure $\mu(t)$ in the integral representation \eqref{Laplace-mu(t)-INT} for $f(x)=\dfrac1{\arctan x}$?**

The following references contain the concepts and the questions stated above.

1. C. Berg, *Integral representation of some functions related to the gamma function*, Mediterr. J. Math. **1** (2004), no. 4, 433--439; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-004-0022-6.
2. Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, *A property of logarithmically absolutely monotonic functions and the logarithmically complete monotonicity of a power-exponential function*, University Politehnica of Bucharest Scientific Bulletin Series A---Applied Mathematics and Physics **72** (2010), no. 2, 21--30.
3. Feng Qi and Ravi P. Agarwal, *On complete monotonicity for several classes of functions related to ratios of gamma functions*, Journal of Inequalities and Applications **2019**, Paper No. 36, 42 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1186/s13660-019-1976-z.
4. Feng Qi and Chao-Ping Chen, *A complete monotonicity property of the gamma function*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **296** (2004), no. 2, 603--607; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2004.04.026.
5. R. L. Schilling, R. Song, and Z. Vondracek, *Bernstein Functions---Theory and Applications*, 2nd ed., de Gruyter Studies in Mathematics **37**, Walter de Gruyter, Berlin, Germany, 2012; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110269338.

Comment: The function already fails the definition given for $n=0$ because  $\arctan x \leq 1$ on $(0,1)\subset (0,\infty)$

Comment: @NinadMunshi I cannot undertand what you wrote: where fails? why fails? Please note that $n\ge1$, that is, $n>0$, or say, $n\ne0$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi It is well known that $\arctan x<1$ on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})\subset(0,\infty)$. This has no any contradiction to the definitions of the completely monotonic function and the logarithmically completely monotonic function.

Comment: Ah I see, so the definition for the logarithmic version is just that the logarithmic derivative of the function is an absolutely monotonic function on its own. Then I was looking at the wrong function.

Comment: @NinadMunshi The definition for the logarithmic version is just that the negative of the logarithmic derivative of the function, $-(\ln f)'$, is a completely monotonic function, not an absolutely monotonic function, on its own. As for logarithmically absolutely monotocnic functions, please refer to the second paper by B.-N. Guo and F. Qi mentioned above.

Comment: @qifeng618
 https://issuesofanalysis.petrsu.ru/journal/content_list_en.php?id=14139

Comment: @DSD Thank you for your timely information. I will carefully read the paper at https://doi.org/10.15393/j3.art.2021.10570, titled "A SOLUTION TO QI’S EIGHTH OPEN PROBLEM ON COMPLETE MONOTONICITY" published in Problemy Analiza--Issues of Analysis by A. Venkata Lakshmi.

Comment: See also discussions at the web site https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_the_reciprocal_of_the_inverse_tangent_a_logarithmically_completely_monotonic_function_on_right-half_line

Comment: @DSD I just now skimmed the paper "A. Venkata Lakshmi, A solution to Qi's eighth open problem on complete monotonicity, Problemy Analiza--Issues of Analysis vol. 10 (28) (2021), no. 3, in press; https://doi.org/10.15393/j3.art.2021.10570" and found that there existed fatal errors in the proof of the logarithmically complete monotonicity of the reciprocal $\frac{1}{\arctan x}$. I will contact with the author for further confirmation of those errors I found just now.

Comment: About in 2008 or earlier, I guessed that the reciprocal $\frac{1}{\arctan x}$ should be a logarithmically completely monotonic function on $(0,\infty)$. After I tried to and failed to verify or deny this guess many times, I announced this problem in the article “Feng Qi and Ravi P. Agarwal, On complete monotonicity for several classes of functions related to ratios of gamma functions. Journal of Inequalities and Applications, 2019, Paper No. 36, 42 pages; https://doi.org/10.1186/s13660-019-1976-z” as the eighth open problem. Till now we can see the difficulty to confirm or deny this guess.

Comment: @qifeng618 I guessed that the proof of the theorem is correct.  Why you plot only  $\sin(n\times \arcsin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}))$? Plot the  entire expression.

Comment: For $n=1$,  $-(\log(f))^{'}  =  \frac{1}{\arctan(x)}\sin( \arcsin(  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}})  )>0$  i.e.,  the entire expression  is positive on $(0, \infty).$

Comment: For $n=2$, $(\log(f))^{''}=\frac{1}{(\arctan(x))^2} ( -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \sin( \arcsin( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}  )     ))^2+ \frac{1}{\arctan(x)}[\frac{1}{1+x^2} \sin( 2 \arcsin( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}) )    ]>0$ for all $(0, \infty).$

Comment: Similar computation shows that $-(\log f)^{'''}>0$ for all $(0, \infty).$

Comment: @DSD What you computed just only means that my guess is possibly true, but not implies that the proof given by A. Venkata Lakshmi is correct. Only if one can understand by eyes clearly, obviously, apparently, directly, straightforwardly, and even trivially that the sign of the $n$-th derivative $\bigl(\ln \frac{1}{\arctan x}\bigr)^{(n)}$ is $(-1)^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ on $(0,\infty)$, the proof can be regarded as being correct. Till now by my eyes I don't think the proof by A. Venkata Lakshmi is correct, although my guess should be true. I need the author to explain more about his/her proof.

Comment: @DSD I think that your sentense "Similar computation shows that $-(\log f)'''>0$ for all $(0,\infty)$" is not correct, because the function $\sin\Bigl(n\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\Bigr)$ for all $n\ge3$ is not constantly positive or negative on $(0,\infty)$: it will change signs on $(0,\infty)$ more and more frequently when $n$ becomes larger and larger. Now I am almost sure that the proof by A. Venkata Lakshmi for the logarithmically complete monotonicity of the reciprocal $\frac1{\arctan x}$ is not correct, is wrong.

Comment: For large $n$ and for all $x\in (0, \infty)$ the function $f(x)= \sin(n x)$ changes signs positive and negative infinitely many times but, it does not mean that the function $1+\sin(nx)$ changes signs.

Comment: @DSD It is trivial that the function $1+\sin(nx)$ does not change its sign, but this has nothing to do with the proof given by A. Venkata Lakshmi. Your answer is out of the scope we are discussing. Okay?

Comment: Logically and mathematically, what is a proof of a theorem, a proposition, a claim, a problem, a guess, and a conjecture? For example, is the proof given by A. Venkata Lakshmi a real proof of the logarithmically complete monotonicity of the reciprocal $\frac1{\arctan x}$? I don’t find any error, I don’t find any mistake, in the proof, but why do I decline to admit the proof? I should be very happy that my own guess or conjecture or problem were proved, why do I deny the proof? Nobody can easily and directly judge…by eyes or existed conclusions from the proof, so the proof is not a real proof.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129736/discussion-between-qifeng618-and-dsd).

Comment: The word "inconvincible" is better for descrbing the proof of the logarithmically complete monotonicity of the reciprocal $\frac1{\arctan x}$ in the paper "A. Venkata Lakshmi, A solution to Qi's eighth open problem on complete monotonicity, Problemy Analiza--Issues of Analysis vol. 10 (28) (2021), no. 3, in press; https://doi.org/10.15393/j3.art.2021.10570". From now on I will stop talking this proof. Thank you, bye bye.

Comment: It seems that a correct proof for this question has been announced at https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.09960v1.        Qi’s conjecture on logarithmically complete monotonicity of the reciprocal of the inverse tangent function